# Spring Boot @ModelAttribute include other model using string key

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm a spring newbie.

I have a Model like below.

```
User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}

PowerUser {
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    private Integer point;
}

Controller {
    registerPowerUser(@ModelAttribute PowerUser powerUser) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(powerUser);
    }
}
```

I could call controller with **?user=1**

But, I changed User like this.

```
User {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String serial_number;
}
```

This code is not work with **?user=serial_number**

Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.project.domain.User] for property 'user';...

Is it impossible to use auto reference using String id?

Comment: Are you trying to use serial_number as your identifier?

Comment: I tested the user=1 case on my machine using Spring 4.2.5 and it didn't work. What version of spring are you using ?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4.1. Sorry I changed title.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was repository.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
```

to

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
```

works well.